# Spin(7)-instanton

Tags: riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry, gauge-theory, holonomy

Let $M$ be a Spin$(7)$-manifold with a spin-bundle $S=S_+\oplus S_-$. There's an obvious connection on $S$ which comes from lifting the Levi-Civita connection. And it induces a connection on the determinant bundle of $S_+:$ let's call it LC. I have heard before that $\pi^2_7(F_{LC})=0$, i.e., it's a Spin$(7)$-instanton. I don't know the proof, any reference or proof is welcome.